# log file that shows CGI errors on GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I was unable to locate the log file that shows, say, "file not found" from a cgi script.

I know it probably is under /var/log, but a global find yields nothing, may be the file is readable by root only?

```
$ uname -a
Linux boxXXX.bluehost.com 3.12.35.1418668052 #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 20:04:02 CST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: There are a lot of **it depends...** wrapped up in your question. What produces the error? `apache`, etc... What log facility do you have? (`syslog-ng` or `systemd journal`), What have you tried in your attempts to locate the error? Was it actually logged or just displayed on `stderr`? If it is `apache` it would generally be in `/var/log/httpd/error.log` (or the equivalent for your distro)

Comment: I said error from cgi script

Comment: I know, I can call a **cgi script** in many different ways. From a C program, from bash, from apache, etc..

Comment: cgi from a perl script

Comment: I chmod to 444, so file not executable error should go to log file

Comment: See, now we are getting somewhere. If you simply called it from `perl` and not via your web server, the message probably just went to `stderr` and not a log.

Comment: it's from webserver, I said cgi

Comment: I hope you don't think I was picking on you, I was just trying to get clear in my mind what your situation was so I could help you (hopefully). See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Since the message was generated as a result of a call to the apache webserver, any error written to `stderr` (**not** `stdout`) by the cgi script will be recorded in the apache `Error Log` (see: [**Error Log**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html) ) To read/`grep`/whatever the error log, you must have sufficient read permission to both the log directory **and** the log file.

The log file can be in one of a number of locations. (usually in `/var/log/httpd` or `/var/log/apache` depending on distro) and usually as (`error_log` in linux or `error.log` in windows/OS2). Both are controlled by the `ErrorLog` directive in `httpd.conf`.

If you have read access to the log, you can simply `grep 'file not found' /var/log/httpd/error_log` (or the correct name for your setup) to find the entries. If not, you will either need `sudo` or `su` access to read the file as root, or you will need to complain loudly to the sysadmin that you do not have sufficient access. If you have tried all of the above and still are having difficulty, leave a comment and I will look further into it.

You can also tailor the format for logging cgi errors through `mod_cgi` or equivalent. See: [**CGI Debugging**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_cgi.html)

Answer (score 0):

The log file depends of your configuration. For example, with Apache 2.4 under Debian 8.0, you can have :

```
$ ls -l /var/log/apache2/error*
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  212 mai    7 19:20 error.log
...
```

You must be root or in the group adm for read the file 
/var/log/apache2/access.log.

If you looking for "string to find" in the file "/var/log/apache2/error.log",
you can do some like that :

```
$ sudo grep "string to find" /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Comment: `access.log` wouldn't show **errors** now would it? Isn't there another separate log for that with `apache`?

Answer (score 0):

You should see logs from your web server, for example with Apache on Debian you should look /var/log/apache2/*.log

You can use grep recursively on /var/log as root

```
grep "file not found" -R /var/log/*
```